# How to build groovy-2.5.8.jar?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to build following project

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch GROOVY_2_5_8 https://github.com/apache/groovy.git
```

with "gradle build" and there are following problems

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':codenarcTools'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':codenarc'.
   > Could not resolve com.googlecode:openbeans:1.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.googlecode:openbeans:1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/melix/thirdparty-apache/com/googlecode/openbeans/1.0/openbeans-1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/melix/thirdparty-apache/com/googlecode/openbeans/1.0/openbeans-1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I need to build groovy-2.5.8.jar form sources, could you tell me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Bintray (jcenter) got killed by jfrog. You'll need to hope those dependencies are on maven central, otherwise you're going to need to find a way to build them yourself

Comment: Had a quick go, and it goes deeper than just that...  Why do you need to build Groovy 2.5.8?  Maybe there's some other way?

Comment: @tim_yates There are bureaucratic reasons. I must provide sources for build or report that sources are unreachable

Comment: @tim_yates When I have changed jacenter to mavenCentral, I got message "> Project :groovy-console declares a dependency from configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :groovy-console."